# Combining xpath queries

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have multiple `xpath` queries that I am trying to combine.

To this end, I have 2 questions:

1:
I am primarily interested in bold text, and in my HTML documents, the text may either be in one of the following forms:

1. `<font style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold ...">`
2. `<p style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold ...">`
3. `<div style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold ...">`

Currently, my syntax of capturing these is :

```
//font[re:test(@style, 'FONT-WEIGHT.?:.?bold', 'i')] | //p[re:test(@style, 'FONT-WEIGHT.?:.?bold', 'i')] | //div[re:test(@style, 'FONT-WEIGHT.?:.?bold', 'i')]
```

While this does work, it certainly is not elegant. Is there a way to search for `font` or `p` or `div` with the same condition?

2: Few of the text may also be in `<h1>`, `<h2>` ... `<h5>`. Is there a way to combine all and give one xpath query for the headers? Something like `//h*`?

Comment: I think `(//font | //p | //div)[re:test(@style, 'FONT-WEIGHT.?:.?bold', 'i')]` does it.

Comment: `re:test()` is not a standard function in XPath. Where does it come from? The calibre tool has such a function: https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/xpath.html#term-re-test.

Comment: @tdelaney works like a charm! I had another tiny related question. I have edited my question to add that as well. If I should put that as a separate question, let me know, I will undo the edit. Could you please put your comment in the answer so I can accept it? Thanks :)

Comment: @mzjn Yes, it is not standard function, I searched for ways of combining xpath with regular expressions in ```lxml``` ```python``` and arrived at my expression after testing it out on different types of inputs.

Comment: So you are using EXSLT? http://exslt.org/regexp/index.html, https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.XPath-class.html

Comment: I'm not sure about the wildcards in node names, but it is available in tests as `name()`, so maybe `*[re:test(name(), "h\d", "i")]`.

Comment: Alternative : `(//*[starts-with(name(),"h") and string-length(name())=2]|//font|//p|//div)[re:test(@style, 'FONT-WEIGHT.?:.?bold', 'i')]`